# Physical Meaning of Over- / Underdetermined Acoustic Eigenvalue Problem

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acoustics, eigenvalue, normal-modes

I am performing an eigenmode study on a system of acoustic ducts.  The system consists of two large cylindrical volumes connected by several smaller cylindrical volumes (modeling a combustion chamber coupled by a series of injectors to a propellant dome).  I write the solution for the pressure and velocity in the two large chambers as an series expansion in the normal modes of a cylinder.  Within the injectors, I assume the motions to be purely longitudinal.  Below are simplified versions of the expressions I'm using:

In the oxidizer dome:

$$ p'_O = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty \psi_{nm}(r,\theta)\left[A_{nm}^{(O+)}e^{-ik_{nm}z} + A_{nm}^{(O-)}e^{ik_{nm}z}\right] $$

In the $l^{th}$ injector:

$$ p'_l = A^{(l+)}e^{-ik_{nm}z} + A^{(l-)}e^{ik_{nm}z} $$

... and in the combustor:

$$ p'_C = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty \psi_{nm}(r,\theta)\left[A_{nm}^{(C+)}e^{-ik_{nm}z} + A_{nm}^{(C-)}e^{ik_{nm}z}\right] $$

with corresponding expressions for acoustic particle velocity obtained from the linearized momentum equations.  Now, the natural frequencies of the composite system are determined by applying impedance boundary conditions on the upstream and downstream bounding surfaces, and matching conditions at the interfaces between the three regions.

Suppose there are $L$ injectors, and truncate the number of azimuthal and radial modes considered to $M$ and $N$ respectively.  Then there should be $4(N+1)(M+1)+2L$ unknowns total.  We require continuity of acoustic pressure and acoustic velocity at every interface between every injector and the adjacent chamber, for a total of $4L$ conditions.  The impedance boundary conditions mean that one of the $A_{nm}^{(O\pm)}$ and $A_{nm}^{(C\pm)}$ can be written in terms of the other, thus reducing the number of unknowns to $2(N+1)(M+1)+2L$.

Normally in such acoustics problems, we put all the equations in a homogeneous matrix-vector form

$$ F\vec{A}=0 $$

where $\vec{A}$ is a vector containing all of the unknowns.  The system admits a nontrivial solution only when $\det(F)=0$.  This yields a transcendental equation to be solved (numerically) for the complex frequencies and associated mode shapes.  The problem I am encountering is that the matrix system I recover with the formulation sketched above is generally not square.  I could form the system $F^TF\vec{A}=0$ and do the same calculation with $\det(F^TF)=0$, but I am unclear as to any physical implications of this?

### TLDR

My questions are, given the model setup I described:

1) Have I counted the number of unknowns $A$ incorrectly, and if so, how many should there be?

2) Either way, will the results I get from solving $\det(F^TF)=0$ have any physical meaning for arbitrary truncations $N$ and $M$?